# Java - A* algorithm walks into unwalkable tiles

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I'm writing automation scripts for a popular game, and part of it requires a pathfinder to walk extended distances.

I wrote this A* pathfinder to achieve this, but there are a few problems with it:

- Sometimes, the pathfinder will go into unwalkable tiles which will eventually lead to it going to the top corners of the map and then out of bounds
- The pathfinder will also get lost and go a long way away from the desired position and then back, leaving a path of 10000+ nodes even though there's only a distance of about 100 tiles sometimes

Here is my AStar.java:

```
    package Webwalker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.osbot.rs07.api.map.Position;
import org.osbot.rs07.script.Script;

import Pickpocketer.PickpocketScript;

public class AStar {
    List<Position> open, closed;
    List<PathTile> holdingList;

    Position s, e, current;

    int horizontalCost, diagonalCost, index;

    Script scr;

    public AStar(Script script) {
        open = new ArrayList<Position>();
        closed = new ArrayList<Position>();
        holdingList = new ArrayList<PathTile>();
        horizontalCost = 10;
        index = 0;
        diagonalCost = 14;
        scr = script;
    }

    public List<Position> findPath(Position start, Position end) {
        s = current = start;
        closed.add(s);
        holdingList.add(new PathTile(start, 0, 0, null));
        e = end;
        while (!nextToEnd()) {
            //scr.log("Finding next node");
            PathTile[] nodes = getAdjacent(current);
            PathTile node = getLeastCost(nodes);
            current = node.p;
            if (!node.walkable) {
                scr.log("Node " + node.p + " - f " + node.f);
            }
            closed.add(current);
            open.remove(current);
            Position mapP = PickpocketScript.map.getMapPos(current);
            int x = mapP.getX();
            int y = mapP.getY();
            PickpocketScript.map.drawPixel(x, y, node.walkable);
            //holdingList.add(node);
            //scr.log(current);

            index++;
        }
        /*scr.log("Cleaning nodes!");
        List<Position> actualPath = new ArrayList<Position>();
        for (PathTile pt : holdingList) {
            if (pt == null || pt.parent == null) continue;
            if (pt.parent.p.equals(start)) {
                actualPath.add(pt.parent.p);
                break;
            }
            if (pt.p.equals(start)) break;
            actualPath.add(pt.parent.p);
            Position mapP = PickpocketScript.map.getMapPos(pt.parent.p);
            int x = mapP.getX();
            int y = mapP.getY();
            PickpocketScript.map.drawPixel(x, y, pt.parent.walkable);
        }*/
        scr.log("Finished finding " + closed.size() + " nodes");
        //Collections.reverse(actualPath);
        return closed;
    }

    public boolean nextToEnd() {
        int mh = ManhattenValue(current);
        return (mh < 21);
        //return false;
    }

    public int[] distance(Position a, Position b) {
        int x = Math.abs(a.getX() - b.getX());
        int y = Math.abs(a.getY() - b.getY());
        return new int[] { x, y };
    }

    public PathTile getLeastCost(PathTile[] nodes) {
        int lowestIndex = 0;
        int lowestF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            //if (!nodes[i].walkable) scr.log("Node " + nodes[i].p + " - f " + nodes[i].f +" getleastcost");
            if (nodes[i] != null && nodes[i].walkable && nodes[i].f < lowestF && !closed.contains(nodes[i].p)) {

                lowestF = nodes[i].f;
                lowestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        //scr.log(lowestIndex);
        return nodes[lowestIndex];
    }

    public PathTile[] getAdjacent(Position p) {
        PathTile[] nodes = new PathTile[8];
        int x = p.getX();
        int y = p.getY();
        PathTile old = null;
        if (holdingList.size() > 0) old = holdingList.get(holdingList.size() - 1);

        Position newNode = new Position(x - 1, y - 1, p.getZ()); //top left
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        int h = OctileValue(newNode);
        int g = diagonalCost;
        nodes[0] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);
        //nodes[0] = nodes[2] = nodes[4] = nodes[5] = nodes[7] = null;

        newNode = new Position(x, y - 1, p.getZ()); //top centre
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = horizontalCost;
        nodes[1] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        newNode = new Position(x + 1, y - 1, p.getZ()); //top right
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = diagonalCost;
        nodes[2] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        newNode = new Position(x - 1, y, p.getZ()); //centre left
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = horizontalCost;
        nodes[3] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        /* Centre centre would be "p", so we skip it (we are not moving back to p) */

        newNode = new Position(x + 1, y, p.getZ()); //centre right
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = horizontalCost;
        nodes[4] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        newNode = new Position(x - 1, y + 1, p.getZ()); //bottom left
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = diagonalCost;
        nodes[5] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        newNode = new Position(x, y + 1, p.getZ()); //bottom centre
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = horizontalCost;
        nodes[6] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        newNode = new Position(x + 1, y + 1, p.getZ()); //bottom right
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = diagonalCost;
        nodes[7] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);

        /*PathTile[] temp = nodes.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (!temp[i].walkable) {
                nodes[i] = null;
            }
        }*/

        return nodes;
    }

    public int OctileValue(Position start) { //This is our "H" value
        int x = start.getX();
        int y = start.getY();

        int horizontal = Math.abs(x - e.getX());
        int vertical = Math.abs(y - e.getY());
        //return Math.max(horizontal, vertical) * horizontalCost; //bad algorithm lol
        //return (horizontal + vertical) * horizontalCost; //Manhatten

        //double tieBreaker = (1.0 + (diagonalCost / ManhattenValue(start)));
        if (horizontal == 0 && vertical == 0) return 0;

        //int h = horizontalCost * (horizontal + vertical) + (diagonalCost - 2 * horizontalCost) * Math.min(horizontal, vertical);

        int h = Math.max(horizontal, vertical) + (diagonalCost - horizontalCost) * Math.min(horizontal, vertical);

        //h *= (tieBreaker);
        return h; //Octile distance
    }

    public int ManhattenValue(Position start) {
        int x = start.getX();
        int y = start.getY();

        int horizontal = Math.abs(x - e.getX());
        int vertical = Math.abs(y - e.getY());
        return (horizontal + vertical) * horizontalCost;
    }

}

class PathTile {
    public Position p;
    public int g, h, f;
    public boolean walkable;
    public PathTile parent;

    public PathTile(Position pos, int G, int H, PathTile par) {
        p = pos;
        g = G;
        h = H;
        if (par != null) {
            g += par.g;
            parent = par;
        }
        if (h == 0) f = 0;
        else f = g + h;
        System.out.println(p + " - g " + g + " - h " + h + " - f " + f);
        walkable = (PickpocketScript.map.isWalkable(pos));

        if (!walkable) {
            f = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that these tiles are unwalkable because they have an F value of int.maxvalue (as defined in PathTile class)

A Position in this scenario simply has an int for x,y,z.

I'm not too sure how to fix these problems, as I'm quite new to writing algorithms like this :)

Comment: With this much code, without knowing the logic behind this and without a running example i am not sure if this problem is solvable by us.

Comment: @KevinEsche An example would be: List<Position> nodes = new AStar(Script object).findPath(new Position(3333, 3333, 0), new Position(1234, 1234, 0)); - The function getLeastCost() will find the node that has the lowest F value given an array of PathTile, the getAdjacent() function will simply get the 8 surrounding tiles for the given position as well as calculating g, h, and f values for each one. The nextToEnd() function simply sees if we are next to the end position (e)

Comment: I suggest you write some small tests and keep increasing the size of the testmaze until your algorithm fails, then debug that.

Comment: @Manu the problem is that it can fail at any distance, it's failed at a size 10, size 100, and I can't see why.

Comment: i wont answer on this because i am not really sure, but i think you are calculating the distance wrong, check out [this site](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm). you can´t just add the  difference between x1-x2 and y1-y2 you need to use the pythagoras

Comment: @AdamM That's why I suggest to create a testmaze, as small as possible, where your algorithm fails...

Comment: @KevinEsche I used [This site](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html) for the Ocilte heuristic (just multiplied by 10)

Comment: @AdamM what is the `distance` function supposed to do, and what are you trying to achive with `dist[0] + dist[1]`

Comment: @KevinEsche The distance function is there for the nextToEnd function to see if they are next to the end node, either diagonally or horizontally. You can also check [here](https://gyazo.com/bd3fcd3c703d38bae78d5b0db6e31a3a) for a visual example of what I mean: a magenta pixel represents an unwalkable tile (they are all spaced 1px apart because 2px on the map = 1 tile)

Comment: This does not look like A*. This is a greedy search. You don't use the open list (neighbors of the current node should be added to it) and you don't look for the best node in the open list. Do this and it might become an A* implementation.

Comment: @NicoSchertler would this fix the walking into unwalkable tiles problem?

Comment: If you implement it correctly, then yes. But it shouldn't happen with a correctly implemented greedy search neither.

Comment: Am I crazy, or are you using the same ArrayList for open and closed? I mean, if you want two ArrayLists, you should be creating two ArrayLists.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I'm initing them both in the same line, is that a problem?

Comment: `open = closed = new ArrayList<Position>();`
Yes, I think your are setting them to be the same empty ArrayList.
Just put them on separate lines: it's clearer, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't even work this way. The constructor needs to be called each time you want a blank ArrayList. Good catch @Erick G. Hagstrom!

Comment: Hi guys, I have updated my implementation (edited my original post), however sometimes the pathfinder will still get lost (see [this example](https://gyazo.com/063bfe6ce87e66821ee6b2a9639c10ba) where the green blob is the start and the blue blob is the end, with magenta being unwalkable and the red being each pathfinder node), you can see that it still gets lost. I'm not sure how to fix this still :/

Answer (score 0):

Your `findPath()` method looks like it's performing a greedy best-first search. Check the line `PathTile node = getLeastCost(nodes);`... You are selecting the least-cost node from among the neighbors of the current PathTile, not from among the entries in the open set. Instead, use a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) sorted by *f*-value for the open list and get your next node from the head of the open list.

**Additional Resources:** I recommend you follow Wikipedia's [A* Search Algorithm Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode). Also, you may want to check out the introduction to A* at [Redblobgames.com](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html).

**Final Consideration:** When working with pathfinding in a grid graph, it is helpful to use an enum to define the directions. This makes your code more readable and maintainable. Here's an example:

```
enum Direction{
    TOP_LEFT(-1,-1,diagonalCost),
    TOP_CENTER(0,-1,horizontalCost),
    TOP_RIGHT(1,-1,diagonalCost),
    MIDDLE_LEFT(-1,0,horizontalCost),
    MIDDLE_RIGHT(1,0,horizontalCost),
    BOTTOM_LEFT(-1,1,diagonalCost),
    BOTTOM_CENTER(0,1,horizontalCost),
    BOTTOM_RIGHT(1,1,diagonalCost);

    public final int x;
    public final int y;
    public final int cost;

    Direction(int x, int y, int cost){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

Your (uncorrected) `getAdjacent` method can be simplified to the following:

```
public PathTile[] getAdjacent(Position p) {
    PathTile[] nodes = new PathTile[8];
    int x = p.getX();
    int y = p.getY();
    PathTile old = null;
    if (holdingList.size() > 0) old = holdingList.get(holdingList.size() - 1);

    for(Direction d: Direction.values()){
        newNode = new Position(x+ d.x, y + d.y, p.getZ()); //top centre
        if (!open.contains(newNode)) open.add(newNode);
        h = OctileValue(newNode);
        g = d.cost;
        nodes[d.ordinal()] = new PathTile(newNode, g, h, old);
    }

    return nodes;
}
```